# Совместная работа Resharper и CodeRush

Tags: devexpress, visual-studio-2013, resharper, рефакторинг

Можно ли как-то заставить совместно, бесконфликтно, работать `CodeRush` и `Resharper` в `VS 2013`?

Просто в `CodeRush` есть те фишки которых нет в `Resharper`, и наоборот.

И хотелось бы совместить функционал для самой комфортной работы.

Answer (score 1):

В CodeRush нет схемы совместимости с Resharper. Но так же не замечено каких-либо проблем при совместной работе.

Если вы обнаружили какие-либо конфликты, то пожалуйста сообщите в [центр поддержки](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) и подробно опишите проблемную ситуацию.

Comment: А как на счет совместной работы? не будет ли это приводить к тормозам студии и т.д?

Comment: Ну здесь можно однозначно сказать, что будет. Посудите сами: студия парсит исходный код и строит семантическое дерево, CodeRush и Resharper делает тоже самое. Естественно это значительно добавляет памяти и будет приводить к некоторому замедлению.

Comment: Единственный напрашивающийся выход, это открытие доступа к дереву из самой студии, чтобы не дублировать работу, что и будет сделано в Visual Studio 2015 с помощью  Roslyn https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn